# struct definition error but only if a function is previously defined

Tags: c++, arduino

This simple piece of Arduino (C++) code fails with error `myType does not define a type`.
It works if I comment out the `doNothing` function, or if I move the function after the definition of the `struct`.

What's going on?

```cpp
//it works if this is commented out
void doNothing() { }

struct myType {
  int x;
};

myType f(){ //error here: myType does not define a type
  myType m;
  m.x = 5;
  return m;
}

void setup() {
  myType p = f();
  int x = p.x;
}

void loop() {
}
```

EDIT:
Declaring the `struct` with `typedef` doesn't help:

```
//it works if this is commented out
void doNothing() { }

typedef struct { //<-- using typedef
  int x;
} myType ;       // <-- type name at the end

myType f(){
  myType m;
  m.x = 5;
  return m;
}

void setup() {
  myType p = f();
  int x = p.x;
}

void loop() {
}
```

The error is still:

```
error: 'myType' does not name a type
 myType f(){
 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type should be `struct myType`  because you did not declare it as a data type:

```
struct myType f(){ // this should work
    myType m;
    m.x = 5;
    return m;
}
```

if you want to define it as a type to be consiered by the compiler, you need to use the typedef keyword to defines it an alias for the structure:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
} myType;

myType f(){ // Now myType does define a type
    myType m;
    m.x = 5;
    return m;
}
```

For more information about typedef visit [this c++ reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef).

Comment: Tried, and I get the same error, see updated question.

Comment: @CristianDiaconescu you're missing the order: the correct one `typedef struct {..} myType;`, myType sould appear at the last to considered as the alias name: correct usage is  `typdef <data_type> <alias_name>`

Comment: Updated again, using `typedef struct { ... } myType ; ` . Still fails. 
The 1st suggestion (`struct myType f()`)  works though.

Comment: @CristianDiaconescu I've just tryied to compile you're updated code with g++7.5 and it work fine.  Please make sure you're not using the myType befaore, it's decalration. Could you post the entire error message from your compiler ?

Comment: @CristianDiaconescu asn the comment of  Juraj refers to a [known bug](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/66530/class-enum-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/66536#66536) in arduino IDE, you should avoid defining functions before declaring the typedef data type.